# Can't remove JComponents from JPanel in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, mouseevent

I have a basic drawer application and when I draw a new line I have to delete the last one. Here is my code:

```
public class DrawLine extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private int x0, y0;
    private MyLine ml;
    private JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DrawLine frame = new DrawLine();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public DrawLine() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panel.addMouseListener(this);;


    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        for (Component c : panel.getComponents()) {
            panel.remove(c);
        }
        x0 = e.getX();
        y0 = e.getY();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {


        if(ml == null){
            ml = new MyLine(x0, y0, e.getX(), e.getY());
            panel.add(ml);
        }
        else{

            ml = new MyLine(x0, y0, e.getX(), e.getY());
            ml.paintcomponent(getGraphics());
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my Line class too:

```
public class MyLine extends JComponent{
    private int x0, y0, x1, y1;

    public MyLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1){
        this.x0 = x0;
        this.y0 = y0;
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
    }

    public void paintcomponent(Graphics gr){
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        gr.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
    }
}
```

In the mousePressed event listener I use a for loop where all the components get removed from the panel, but it does not work. I tried to use panel.removeAll() too, without success.

Comment: If you add `panel.repaint()` after removing the components it will work. However I would strongly recommend that MyLine shouldn't extend JComponent. Override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method in the panel that you use for drawing (in your case `panel`) and draw the line inside that method. This way you don't have to remove components and in my opinion it's the better and safer way to do it.

Comment: Agree with @LuxxMiner, `MyLine` should not be a `JComponent`.  It should just offer a `draw(Graphics)` method that can be called by whatever component **is** rendering it.

Comment: You will need to `revalidate` before you call `repaint` to force the layout manager to update the UI

Comment: Thanx, but If now I resize the frame the components disappeare. Why?